# Odoo 13 Gantt View "groub_by" record counts

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, gantt-chart, odoo-13

---

In odoo 13 new gantt view, when using filter "group_by", a record count is added when it spans the same date period:
[image: Odoo 13 Gantt View Groub By record count on same date period]

Are you aware of any XML option to remove this count?

---

*What I've tried:*

I could add a `display: none;` to this class: `.o_gantt_view .o_gantt_row_group .o_gantt_pill_wrapper.o_gantt_consolidated_wrapper`, but I can't add it directly on the XML view, right?

I also tried to add the below script to the form view, not working either.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".o_gantt_view .o_gantt_row_group .o_gantt_pill_wrapper.o_gantt_consolidated_wrapper").hide();
  });
</script>
```